# NDSolve is not always easy to handle

Tags: differential-equations

I solve the PDE system analytically and numerically and get totally different results. Should there be a solution to the problem of the numerical solution, one must ask oneself - do you know the correct result beforehand? Unfortunately, Mathematica is still very weak in solving analytical PDEs.

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x];
bcs = {Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][u][1, t] == 0};
ic = u[x, 0] == x;
sol = First@DSolve[{pde, bcs, ic}, u, {x, t}] /. K[1] -> n
```

[image]

```
U[x_, t_] = u[x, t] /. sol /. \[Infinity] -> 20 // Activate;
Plot3D[U[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.8}, PlotTheme -> "Default"]
```

[image]

Check the boundary conditions for compliance.

```
Derivative[1, 0][U][0, t]
0
Derivative[1, 0][U][1, t]
0
```

Now the numerical solution attempt:

```
nsol = First@NDSolve[{pde, bcs, ic}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. nsol, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.8}, PlotTheme -> "Default"]
```

[image]

To the left of the error warning (...), there are sources that can help with problem solving. Unfortunately I did not find any.

Comment: Is this just a statement..or is there a specific question...sorry, im not sure what you’re looking for.

Comment: I want to solve it numericaly.

Comment: To be more specific, add `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}` will resolve your problem.

Comment: @xzczd I found the source in "The Numerical Method of Lines," but not without your help, thank you. I think Maple is more helpful in solving PDEs in many cases.

Comment: Indeed, _Maple_ is more good at **symbolic** PDE solving: https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2019_and_mma_12/index.htm , at least now. But its numeric PDE solver isn't that good, AFAIK.